# Multiple Cassandra in same node

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 nodes. I would like to bring up a 3node cassandra ( 1 Cassandra in 1 node ) and 3 single node cassandra (1 in each node ).

So in 1 node, there is an instance of a 3 node cassandra and single node cassandra.

Can I deploy like this by changing the port number is in use?

Can I use same port number across single node deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this unless you give each cassandra node its own data and commit log volume(s).  Cassandra is optimized for sequential read and write access of its data (SSTables) and if you have multiple Cassandra instances competing for I/O your performance is going to not be very good.

To answer your question, you can do this, there are a number of configuration files in cassandra.yaml you need to change.  Assuming you are using cassandra 2.0 and up these are:

- storage_port
- native_transport_port
- rpc_port

Whatever client(s) you use to interface with cassandra, those need to support specifying alternative ports.   Fortunately the datastax drivers support this. For example the java-driver has a [addContactPointsWithPorts](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#addContactPointsWithPorts(java.util.Collection)) method for specifying contact points with their respective ports for creating a connection to the cassandra cluster.

Again, I would strongly discourage this in a production setting.  Multiple nodes sharing the same disk is discouraged, and mulitple nodes on the same host adds complexity.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Can I point each Cassandra storage to 2 different physical disks in same node to reduce io contention. Is there any performace issue by sharing same proceesor (different jvm)

Comment: That will work better, but to me that's uncharted territory to run multiple cassandra processes on the same host.  I think it will work, but you will want to do some performance testing to ensure the two processes don't step over each other so much.